# stuck to printing pyramid code although my code is correct but my jupyter notebook doesn't print me the exact answer

Tags: python, string, format, console-output

[Screenshot of code and output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fpnxD.jpg)

**Code**

```
num = int(input("Enter the number of rows:"))
for i in range(0,num):
  for j in range(0,num-i-1):
    print(end="")
  for j in range(0,i+1):
    print("*",end="")
  print()
```

**Current output**

```
*
**
***
****
*****
******
```

answer is not exactly the same as PYRAMID, show it in the picture

Comment: What your expected output. Which output do you get? We do not see your pictures. Please [edit]. `print(end="")` does nothing btw. so your whole 1st `j` loop is superflous

Comment: I add a picture so it's show me in the left side rather than in the middle

Comment: Please show the output as text, not as a (bad) image. At least make a proper screenshot.

Comment: Look, mkrieger1 1  actually i am having problem with screenshot in windows8.1 perhaps my windows need new windows, please answer my question from this picture , i am really sorry that i can't complete your requirement and i am a new user help me please

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you want your pyramid to be centered and not leaning to the left side. For that, you have to adjust the spacing before and after the stars in your loops accordingly:

**Changed Code**

```
num = int(input("Enter the number of rows:"))
for i in range(0,num):
  for j in range(0,num-i-1):
    print(end=" ")
  for j in range(0,i+1):
    print("*",end=" ")
  print()
```

**Output**

```
     * 
    * * 
   * * * 
  * * * * 
 * * * * * 
* * * * * *
```

Comment: Kim Tang thank you so much bro i am really really appreciate ur work and its certainly works and GOD bless u and i will pray for u too dude :)

Comment: I'm glad I could help! It would also be nice if you could mark my answer as being "accepted" with the green checkmark. Thank you!